# Changing the display of an element via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a search bar with a toggle button directly above it. The toggle works just fine, but my issue is that I want the form to *start* disabled. My toggle button utilizes the **display** property, but when I set that property through CSS as disabled, the toggle no longer works. I also found that there isn't an attribute for that in HTML, so I'm pretty lost. Here's my Javascript spun into my HTML:

```js
function ToggleSearchBar() {
  var searchbar = document.getElementById("SearchBar");
  if (searchbar.style.display == "none") {
    searchbar.style.display = "";
  } else {
    searchbar.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.search-button form {
  display: none;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-button">
  <p onclick="ToggleSearchBar()">Search</p>
  <form id="SearchBar">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your query here">
  </form>
</div>
```

So to reiterate, I just need the form element to *start* with a **display** of none, while still allowing for my Javascript to function as intended. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you have disabled some element it is not  suppose to work

Comment: I'm not disabling it. I'm simply setting the display property to "none".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the problem here is `element.style.display` accesses inline style property to get the property applied to the element you can use `getComputedStyle` function

```js
    function ToggleSearchBar() {
        var searchbar = document.getElementById("SearchBar");
       var display = getComputedStyle(searchbar).display;

        if (display == "none") {
                searchbar.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                searchbar.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
```

```css
.search-button form {
    display: none;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "search-button">
        <p onclick = "ToggleSearchBar()">Search</p>
        <form id = "SearchBar">
            <input type = "text" placeholder = "Your query here">
        </form>
    </div>
```

and you have to use display `block` instead of empty string as you have a css declaration of `none`.

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks so much

Answer (score 3):

This is because when you set `display=""` it will use its css style which is `none`. You should change display to `block`.
For **hide/show** purpose I would suggest you to use [Ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```js
function ToggleSearchBar() {
  var searchbar = document.getElementById("SearchBar");
  if(searchbar.style.display === '') searchbar.style.display = 'block'
  else searchbar.style.display = searchbar.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none' 
}
```

```css
.search-button form {
        display: none;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<div class = "search-button">
        <p onclick = "ToggleSearchBar()">Search</p>
        <form id = "SearchBar">
            <input type = "text" placeholder = "Your query here">
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: That worked great. Thanks a lot. I'll accept your answer once the site allows it

Comment: The only issue with this approach is that `style.display` looks up inline style properties on the HTML element. If you notice in the running example, you have to press "Search" twice in order for it to show up the first time, then it works normally afterward.

Comment: I have fixed that.